# Unable to publish an ASP.NET webpage on an Azure VM running on Windows server 2016 database

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-development-server, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm-role

Hi I am trying to deploy a website on an Azure VM and I already set all the configuration for make a deployment but this error appears when I tried to publish:

Error Web deployment task failed. (You connected to the remote computer ("saveci1.westus.cloudapp.azure.com") using the Web Administration Service, but it could not be authorized. Make sure you are using the correct username and password, that the site the one you are connecting to exists and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access this site.Get more information at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)
Make sure the site name, user name, and password are correct. If the issue is not resolved, please contact your local or server administrator.
Error details:
You connected to the remote computer ("saveci1.westus.cloudapp.azure.com") through the Web Administration Service, but could not be authorized. Make sure you are using the correct username and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access this site. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.
Remote server error: (401) Not authorized. PoC 0

I follow all the steps from here https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/AspNetVMs/docs/create-asp-net-vm-with-webdeploy.md

Comment: Could you check if you type the correct admin user and password on azure VM when publishing the website in VS?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check if is there any IP restriction configured for the resource group in Azure portal as it could be the reason.

Also i would suggest you to put a fiddler and trace the request which is causing the failure.

please check if you are behind any proxy, if yest then try to connect to a network that does not require this SSO through the proxy or use one of the many other ways to publish that do not require an SSO connection from your machine such as, FTP, VSTS, Git etc… and try to deploy it. Most of the time proxies are the reason which could cause failure in deployment.

As a workaround you could ftp to the site & do deployment via that method .

Hope it helps.